# Opensource Voting System

Tags: php, python, open-source, voting

I'm planning to build a community-driven website with voting functionality similar to StackOverflow (or Digg etc..). I really like SO's voting system where your points are deducted for voting down someone and so on.

Anyway, is there any open-source module/component available that I can plug into my app directly without having to reinvent the wheel? The app will developed probably be in PHP or Python.

Thanks for your comments and advices.

Comment: it depends on which cms,blog,framework you are using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few for Django:

- [django-voting](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/)
- [django-rangevoting](http://code.google.com/p/django-rangevoting/)
- [django-ranking](http://github.com/thauber/django-ranking)

Personally I've only used django-voting.  It has a nice section on using it for a Reddit/SO style voting including templates and using Progressive enhancement: http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting

I think the other projects have some interesting features in terms of custom ranking/sorting methods which is where django-voting can fall short.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Pligg](http://www.pligg.com)

> Pligg started as a simple CMS to let
>   users submit and vote on news
>   articles, and that's still what we do
>   best. Vote on stories that interest
>   you and articles that receive enough
>   votes will appear on the homepage of
>   your Pligg site. Pligg offers a 5 star
>   method for voting or the more
>   traditional numbered voting as seen on
>   sites like Digg, Mixx, or Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its written in PHP ZendFramework

**phpancake**
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/

A questions and answers system, where the validity of the questions and their answers is determined and moderated by the community by a voting system. This open source system is on the lines of Stackoverflow and digg.

Comment: Er no, I'm not creating an SO clone, its not Q&A system at all. BTW, this looks quite unpolished, the layout is a mess.

Comment: yeah it looks realy nice but some bugs are in it

Answer (score 0):

List of Polling tools are given in the website http://myprogrammingblog.com/2011/09/16/web-poll-script-overview-top-5/

http://www.phppoll.org/download.php